# Writing/reading NSData to file failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I have an in-memory cache that I would like to write out to file on `viewWillDisappear` and read in back into memory on `viewDidLoad`. My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSArray *fileArray = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@cache_%d", [fileArray lastObject], self.index];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        self.thumbnailsCache = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSArray *fileArray = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@cache_%d", [fileArray lastObject], self.index];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    [self.thumbnailsCache writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES];
}
```

Based on some NSLog and debugging, it seems to write the file successfully, but on trying to read it simply says file not found. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit: `self.thumbnailsCache` is an `NSDictionary` of `NSData` objects.

Comment: you just check your file in documents cache directory in finder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating your `filePath` incorrectly.

`fileArray` is an array of URL's and not NSStrings (which is what your code is assuming).

So if you're taking the last URL as being the cache directory you want to use, you can create the cache file via something like this:

```
NSURL * cacheURL = (NSURL *)[fileArray lastObject];
if(cacheURL)
{
    NSURL * fileToWrite = [cacheURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@cache_%d", self.index]];
}
```

Or, in the context of your code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSArray *fileArray = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@cache_%d", [fileArray lastObject], self.index];

    NSURL * cacheURL = (NSURL *)[fileArray lastObject];
    if(cacheURL)
    {
        NSURL * fileToRead = [cacheURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@cache_%d", self.index]];
        if(fileToRead && ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileToRead]) {
                self.thumbnailsCache = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:fileToRead];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSArray *fileArray = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@cache_%d", [fileArray lastObject], self.index];

    NSURL * cacheURL = (NSURL *)[fileArray lastObject];
    if(cacheURL)
    {
        NSURL * fileToWrite = [cacheURL URLByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@cache_%d", self.index]];
        if(fileToWrite)
        {
            [self.thumbnailsCache writeToURL:fileToWrite atomically:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:]` takes a `NSString`, not a `NSURL`. An equivalent method for `NSURL` doesn't exist. How do I get the `NSString` filepath?

Comment: Whoops, I didn't thoroughly check my code and didn't catch that `fileExistsAtPath` call.  Instead, you should use NSURL's [`checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:). Hope that helps!